# Running Java using a junction for the executable's folder does not work

Tags: windows, command-line, java

I have just upgraded from Java version 8 to version 12.
The OS is Windows 7 Home.

As Oracle no longer provide a separate JRE, when running a program I need to provide the folder name for the Java executable. To make it easier to change the folder when Java gets updated, I put a junction into one of my folders and added that to my PATH. But it doesn't work. Here's a slightly edited command-line session.

First check the junction and path are OK:

```
D:\Peter\PC>dir jre*

27/09/2019  15:11    <JUNCTION>     JREDir [C:\Program Files\Javajdk-12.0.1\bin]

D:\Peter\PC>dir jredir\java*
 Volume in drive D is DATA
 Volume Serial Number is CE44-C814

 Directory of D:\Peter\PC\jredir

27/09/2019  11:36           148,328 java.dll
27/09/2019  11:36            51,048 java.exe
27/09/2019  11:36           226,664 javaaccessbridge.dll
27/09/2019  11:36            20,840 javac.exe
27/09/2019  11:36            20,840 javadoc.exe
27/09/2019  11:36           174,952 javajpeg.dll
27/09/2019  11:36            20,840 javap.exe
27/09/2019  11:36            51,048 javaw.exe
               8 File(s)        714,560 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  149,081,808,896 bytes free
C:\>path
PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)...ls\Binn\;D:\Peter\PC\JREDir
```

Now try to run Java using the junction name

```
D:\Peter\PC>jredir\java -version
Error: opening registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\JRE'
Error: could not find java.dll
Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.
```

This seems to find the java executable, but needs a registry key. However, doing a cd to the executable's directory works OK!

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1\bin>java -version
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
java version "12.0.1" 2019-04-16
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 12.0.1+12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 12.0.1+12, mixed mode, sharing)
```

as does running it with an explicit directory name:

```
D:\Peter\PC>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1\bin"\java -version
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
java version "12.0.1" 2019-04-16
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 12.0.1+12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 12.0.1+12, mixed mode, sharing)
```

But running it using the path doesn't.

```
C:\>java -version
Error: opening registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\JRE'
Error: could not find java.dll
Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.
```

So I have two questions:

1. Why isn't the junction working? I tried a symlink but that didn't work either.
2. What's needed in the registry to get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question but I am sharing for future reference.

In the example, the junction is one level too deep. It shouldn't be `C:\Program Files\Javajdk-12.0.1\bin` but rather `C:\Program Files\Javajdk-12.0.1`